# Caller ID spoofing in Pakistan using 3CX PBX and SIP trunk

Tags: voip, pbx, 3cx, caller-id

Though `VoIP` is legal in Pakistan but PTA (Pakistan Telecommunication Authority) doesn't want to propagate VoIP `Caller IDs` to the called number. Most carriers replace VoIP Caller IDs with local number. I found just one telco company that sometimes allow VoIP Caller ID to appear at called number. Most of the countries (USA etc.) carriers allow caller ID spoofing. My question is How to send Caller ID with a company's name such as `PepsiCola` or digits `4444` using 3CX PBX with SIP trunk. When I call from `3CX Windows client` most of the time local numbers appear at called numbers. I've set outbound caller id in extension and also in sip trunk outbound parameters From: UserPart I select `"Outbound CallerID" Outbound caller ID taken from extension in management console`.

Answer (score 0):

This is depends of SIP trunk provider set up - You can send anything in this fields, but voip operator would disallow this or replace with own settings.
Further, any CallerID / Contact and another fields in sip communication mus be also allowed in second part of call - for example in my country mobile networks is more restricted about Caller ID then fixed line operators.

Comment: example of voip call: 1.VoIP Phone with extension number -> 2.PBX with trunk to outgoing calls -> 3. caller (yours) SIP provider -> 4. recaiving Provider (second side) -> 5. Phone which recaive call. Each of these points can send another CallerID policy, but more powerful is always right side of "->"